# how to get sidebar fixed to lef side in bootstrap 3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

i'm having some trouble to get a sidebar that is fixed to the left side of the page.

i cant get a side bar but its not fixed to the left and the content of the site is under the sidebar or the bar is at the side but the contend is over lapping .
sow i googel for like a hour and can not find a good solution :s

[Code](http://hastebin.com/ficixitupo.xml)

[Demo](http://svdbphotography.be/nicolai/)

Thx in advc

Comment: I would follow how Bootstrap achieves it in its new dashboard example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

Add a `margin-left` to your `.container` class so that the container of the content gets moved over so it's not on top of your sidebar.

Looks like if you do `margin-left:275px;` it should be pretty nice. You may have to adjust your width of `.container` as well.

Comment: yeah but then i gote something like this : http://i.imgur.com/EDn05BW.png   but i wanne have a side bar like this : http://admindesigns.com/stardom/